# Google Apps mail to domain not received

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I moved servers, and consequently all domains, to my new host about 2-3 days ago. Everything has gone smoothly except for an issue regarding emailing a mailbox hosted on Google Apps on my own domain from the server, for example.

1.1.1.1 hosts example.com.
I have a PHP script on the server hosting example.com to mail admin@example.com for certain things. It will never arrive in my admin@example.com inbox hosted by Google Apps since I've moved servers. It worked fine before.

I know mail is being sent because I can edit the script to email for example: `admin@yahoo.com` or `admin@gmail.com` instead of `admin@example.com` and both arrive in my inbox, though in spam (probably unrelated). I thought this was because the server IP wasn't the same as my old one, and the system was using my old server IP so emails couldn't be forged, so it would need 24-48 hours to propagate the new IP and the mail would start being received. However it's now been almost 72 hours and I still can't email anything on the`@example.com` domain.

Comment: This looks like it might be better off at [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set your SPF record to include the new server as a host for your mail to be sent from?

For example, if your new server's address is 1.1.1.1, your SPF will now look like:

v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:1.1.1.1 ~all

Note, it will take a while depending on your TTL of your l

Here are the relevant articles which should help:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786&topic=2759192&ctx=topic
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework